# Return original argument if csname is not defined

Tags: conditionals

For some `#1`,`#2` I define the `\csname base:#1:#2\endcsname`. Then I define the following

```
\def\data#1#2{\ifcsname base:#1:#2\endcsname \csname base:#1:#2\endcsname\fi}
```

and afterwards

```
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\data{#1}{fname} \data{#1}{lname}}
```

You can see `\data` as a 2-dimensional array with information on users with id `#1`. Now I want to make sure that the original input is printed when the user-id isn't found. I.e. assume I have users `john` and `elvis` with full information. Then `\name{elvis}` will print as `Elvis Presley`. Now I want `#1` printed if `\csname base:#1:#2` is not defined, i.e. `\name{santa}` will print `santa`  since santa is not in my userbase. I tried working with

```
\ifx\data{#1}{fname}\empty #1\else ...\fi
```

but couldn't get it to work. How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to see what you are doing and the best way to answer this with a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), but ignoring this...

The simplest solution would simply be to redefine `\data` as:

```
\def\data#1#2{%
  \ifcsname base:#1:#2\endcsname \csname base:#1:#2\endcsname%
  \else #1%
\fi}
```

but I suspect that this is not what you want as now `\name{santa}` will produce `santa santa`. Instead, I think that you probably want to define something like the following:

```
\newif\ifDataExists
\newcommand\CheckForData[1]{%
  % assuming that fname a reasonable proxy to check for data?
  \ifcsname base:#1:fname\endcsname\DataExiststrue
  \else\DataExistsfalse
  \fi%
}
\newcommand\name[1]{\CheckForData{#1}%
  \ifDataExists{#1}{fname} \data{#1}{lname}\else #1\fi}
```

Now, using your original `\data` command, `\name{santa}` will produce a single `santa`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I'll include a MWE the next time, you can consider egreg's first code block as the MWE for this post.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\data[2]{%
  \ifcsname base:#1:#2\endcsname
    \csname base:#1:#2\endcsname
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\data{#1}{fname} \data{#1}{lname}}

% populate one of the databases (I don't know how you do it)
\expandafter\def\csname base:elvis:fname\endcsname{Elvis}
\expandafter\def\csname base:elvis:lname\endcsname{Presley}

\begin{document}

\name{elvis}

\name{santa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Printing “santa” just once would be possible, but it would also complicate the definition of `\name` using lower level checks.

---

If you used my proposed `expl3` implementation, just a few modifications would provide a `\name` macro that has the property you need:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
id:john1; fname: John; lname: Doe; mail: example@doe.com
id:harry1; fname: Harry; lname: Potter; mail: harry@hogwarts.com
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\storedata}{mm}
 {% pass control to an inner function
  \konewka_add_id:n { #1 }
  \konewka_store_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\readdata}{m}
 {
  \konewka_read_data:n { #1 }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdata}{mm}
 {
  \konewka_item:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\listIDs}{}
 {% just an example
  \seq_use:Nn \g_konewka_id_seq { ,~ }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\name}{m}
 {
  \konewka_if_key:nTF { #1 }
   {
    \konewka_item:nn { #1 } { fname }
    \c_space_tl
    \konewka_item:nn { #1 } { lname }
   }
   {
    \texttt{#1}
   }
 }

%%% variables

% we need a colon with the appropriate category code    
\tl_const:Nx \c_konewka_colon_tl { \tl_to_str:n {:} }
% other variables
\seq_new:N \g_konewka_id_seq

\tl_new:N \l__konewka_id_tl
\seq_new:N \l__konewka_data_temp_seq
\seq_new:N \l__konewka_field_temp_seq
\ior_new:N \g__konewka_read_data_stream

%%% variants of kernel functions
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV , NVV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cxx }

%%% our functions

% check if a key is present in the database
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \konewka_if_key:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \prop_if_exist:cTF { g_konewka_data_#1_prop }
   {
    \prg_return_true:
   }
   {
    \prg_return_false:
   }
 }

% add the new id to a sequence for possible later usage
\cs_new_protected:Nn \konewka_add_id:n
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_konewka_id_seq { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \konewka_add_id:n { V }

% the inner function for \storedata
\cs_new_protected:Nn \konewka_store_data:nn
 {
  % create a property list for an ID
  \prop_new:c { g_konewka_data_#1_prop }
  % split the second argument at semicolons
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__konewka_data_temp_seq { ; } { #2 }
  % populate the property list
  \__konewka_process_entry:n { #1 }
 }

% the inner function for \readdata
\cs_new_protected:Nn \konewka_read_data:n
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g__konewka_read_data_stream { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__konewka_read_data_stream
   {
    % split a line into fields
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__konewka_data_temp_seq { ; } { ##1 }
    % retrieve the first field (ID)
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__konewka_data_temp_seq \l__konewka_id_tl
    % split at colon and set the ID to the second part
    \seq_set_split:NVV \l__konewka_data_field_seq \c_konewka_colon_tl \l__konewka_id_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l__konewka_id_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__konewka_data_field_seq { 2 } }
    % add the id to the list
    \konewka_add_id:V \l__konewka_id_tl
    % populate the property list
    \__konewka_process_entry:V \l__konewka_id_tl
   }
 }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Npn \konewka_item:nn #1 #2
 {% just retrieve the property from the appropriate property list
  \prop_item:cn { g_konewka_data_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

% auxiliary function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__konewka_process_entry:n
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__konewka_data_temp_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:NVn \l__konewka_data_field_seq \c_konewka_colon_tl { ##1 }
    \prop_gput:cxx { g_konewka_data_#1_prop }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__konewka_data_field_seq { 1 } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__konewka_data_field_seq { 2 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__konewka_process_entry:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\readdata{\jobname.csv}
\storedata{uthor1}{fname: Algernon; lname: Uthor; mail: a.uthor@tex.org}
\storedata{riter1}{fname: Walter; lname: Riter; mail: w.riter@latex.org}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
Id & fname & lname & mail \\
\hline
\texttt{john1} & \getdata{john1}{fname} & \getdata{john1}{lname} & \getdata{john1}{mail} \\
\texttt{harry1} & \getdata{harry1}{fname} & \getdata{harry1}{lname} & \getdata{harry1}{mail} \\
\texttt{uthor1} & \getdata{uthor1}{fname} & \getdata{uthor1}{lname} & \getdata{uthor1}{mail} \\
\texttt{riter1} & \getdata{riter1}{fname} & \getdata{riter1}{lname} & \getdata{riter1}{mail} \\
\end{tabular}

\medskip

The IDs are: \listIDs

\medskip

Print names: ``\name{john1}'' and ``\name{santa}''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'd figured this out as well. Is it possible to work out the solution for printing santa just once?

Comment: I might be tempted to use `\csname base:#1:#2\expandafter\endcsname` just in case something odd gets stored.

Comment: How about `\newcommand\data[2]{%
  \ifcsname base:#1:#2\endcsname
    \csname base:#1:#2\endcsname
  \else
    \def\fname{#1}
    \def\lname{}
    \csname#2\endcsname%
  \fi
}`

Comment: Thanks, I had chosen the other implementation from the other post, but I think I'm all going do it in l3. Until then I'm going to use Andrews solution